# Using a generic if statement for all values of an array in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this php statement that collects data from a database table. It loops over all rows and separates them into tables of 2 (home team and away team for that game). I also have radio buttons so the user can pick which team they would like to win for each game. There are 9 games.

```
$games = array();

for($num = 1; $num <= 9; $num++)
{
    $games[$num] = "<table border='1'><tr><b><h4>Game ".$num."</h4></b><th>Home</th><th>Draw</th><th>Away</th></tr>";
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    for($num = 1; $num <= 9; $num++)
    {
        $games[$num] .= 
" <tr>
 <td><input type='radio' id='home".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='".$row['home'.$num]."'  > ".$row['home'.$num]."</td>
 <td>Draw <br /><input type='radio' id='draw".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='0'></td>
 <td>".$row['away'.$num]."<input type='radio' id='away".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='".$row['away'.$num]."'></td>
 </tr>";
    }
}
```

On submit, i want to be able to do something for each game via SELFSUBMIT.

So if a user selects home team for game n, i want to display a message.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    if($_POST['game".$num."'] = ('home'.$num))
    {
        echo ('home'.$num);
    }

}
```

Thats my wrong php code. Please tell me if i can workaround this.

Comment: Shouldn't the comparison operator in `if($_POST['game".$num."'] = ('home'.$num))` be `==` ??. Also, I think you must surround your `inputs` with a `form` tag and make your script check which radio button was selected via its `name` property. i.e. if you have 3 radio's name each one: `radio1`, `radio2` and `radio3` and then when the form is submitted check which radio was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("input[id^=home]").on("click", function(){
        $("#spanDisplay").html( $(this).attr("id") );
        //you can also display $(this).attr("name") or $(this).val() to print the value
    });
});
```

In your html, you can use span or div to display the value of id for example.
So in your span

```
<span id="spanDisplay"></span>
```

UPDATE: using PHP only

```
$games[$num] .= "<form name="aForm" method="POST" action="afterSubmit.php">";

for($num = 1; $num <= 9; $num++){
    $games[$num] .= "<tr><td><input type='radio' id='home".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='".$row['home'.$num]."'> ".$row['home'.$num]."</td>
                     <td>Draw <br /><input type='radio' id='draw".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='0'></td>
                     <td>".$row['away'.$num]."<input type='radio' id='away".$num."' name='game".$num."' value='".$row['away'.$num]."'></td></tr>";
}

$games[$num] .= "</form>";
```

You will need to surround your input with the form tag, submit and post it to the next page for instance afterSubmit.php. So in afterSubmit.php page, you can put something like this:

```
for($num = 1; $num <= 9; $num++){
    if( isset( $_POST['game".$num."'] ) ){
        echo $_POST['game".$num."']; //echo the value
    }
}
```

Comment: i have used form tags, just didnt paste it here. What i want is every time a user clicks the home team radio button, i want something to happen, so thats why i was doing something along the lines of if( isset( $_POST['game".$num."'] = 'home..' )

Comment: what is your value in the form tag for attribute action? It should be `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or the name of the page it self. Just try to take the last code snippet and wrap it in `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { // pasted the code here }`